# Is it possible to launch an external image editor from Textmate?

Tags: macos, textmate

Is it possible to launch an external image editor from the TextMate project drawer? I suppose the same concept would apply to launching any external editor from TextMate.  Right now, if I right-click on the image file, I only have an option to open in Preview or Finder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There is an (official) TM **Bundle** that does what you want--it's called "**ImageBrowser**." I installed recently and i have used it only once. It seems to work fine for the purpose you mentioned in your Question; in particular, it finds images in your current project and displays them in an image browser that runs inside TextMate.

You can get it from the [Macromates SVN Repository](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/).

Answer (score 1):

TextMate respects the Finder's (well, LauchService's) "Open with" choice for each file.  Whichever program would open when you double-click the file in Finder will appear in TextMate's contextual menu.  Simply change this through the Finder's Get Info window for the file in question to the editor of your choice, and TextMate will respect it.  It's dynamically populated, so you don't need to restart TextMate.

As far as I know, there's no method to specify a secondary program beyond the default.

Answer (score 1):

I think no is the answer, but like Matt said, explore the usage of the Services menu.

Comment: No, my answer has nothing to do with the Services menu.  It is possible, based upon **LaunchServices'** currently selected app to open the file (selected through Finder's Get Info Window).